# JQuery Tab not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to get a JQuery Tab (not UI) to play nice while creating dynamic tabs and loading dynamic content from a php file.  The php file is returning a few tables, css, and images.  Everything loads as expected.  I am trying to get additional tabs to be created via href link.  Everything appears to be working except the initial default tab content container that gets created doesn't hide when the other tabs are created or clicked to be active.  Instead, the additional tab's contents are added at the bottom of the initial content container.  If I replace my php file with a simple 'Hello World', everything works fine.  I've combed thru the php data and there are no conflicting element names in the html.  Nothing fancy at all, just html, css, and images.

You can see the sample demo [here](http://coltsdigital.me/armoredkill/tabs.html).

Here's my js:

```
$(function() {
    var total_tabs = 0;
    var pId = 0;
    var pName = "";

    //initialize first tab
    addtab(total_tabs,pId,"Server Details");

    $("a.tb_showTab").click(function() {
        total_tabs++;
        var vId = $(this).attr('hash').replace('#','');
        var pValues = vId.split('|');               
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        addtab(total_tabs,pValues[1],pValues[0]);
        return false;
    });

    function addtab(count,pId,pName) {
        var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
        //no close button on default tabs
        if (pId==0 || pId==1){closetab = ""};

        //Create Tab
        $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">'+pName+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');

        //Create Tab Content
        if (pId==0){
            //load Server Details
            $.get("test5.php",
                {nbRandom: Math.random() },
                function(data){
                    $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+data+'</p>');
                });
            }
        else if (pId==1){
            //load Groups Details
            //eventually replace this with dynamic content from php file
            $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+pName+' content goes here!!</br>ID='+pId+'</p>');
            }
        else {
            //load Person Details
            //eventually replace this with dynamic content from php file
            $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+pName+' content goes here!!</br>ID='+pId+'</p>');
            }
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

        $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
            $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
            $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
            $("#tabcontent p").hide();
            $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
        });

        $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
            // activate the previous tab
            $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
            $("#tabcontent p").hide();
            $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
            $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

            $(this).parent().remove();
            $("#c"+count).remove();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

And here's the html:

```
<a class="tb_showTab" href="#Tab_Name_1|11111" >Add Tab1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="tb_showTab" href="#Tab_Name_2|22222" >Add a Tab2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="tb_showTab" href="#Tab_Name_3|33333" >Add a Tab3</a>    

<div id="container">
    <ul id="tabul">
        <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"></li>
    </ul>            
<div id="tabcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p></p>` within tabcontent does not nest the `<center></center>` tag, within which the actual content is there. Try the following js code - this seems to work.

```
$(function() {
var total_tabs = 0;
var pId = 0;
var pName = "";

//initialize first tab
addtab(total_tabs,pId,"Server Details");

$("a.tb_showTab").click(function() {
    total_tabs++;
    var vId = $(this).attr('hash').replace('#','');
    var pValues = vId.split('|');               
    $("#tabcontent center").hide();
    addtab(total_tabs,pValues[1],pValues[0]);
    return false;
});

function addtab(count,pId,pName) {
    $("#tabcontent p").hide();
    var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
    //no close button on default tabs
    if (pId==0 || pId==1){closetab = ""};

    //Create Tab
    $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">'+pName+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');

    //Create Tab Content
    if (pId==0){
        //load Server Details
        $.get("test5.php",
            {nbRandom: Math.random() },
            function(data){
                $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+data+'</p>');
            });
        }
    else if (pId==1){
        //load Groups Details
        //eventually replace this with dynamic content from php file
        $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+pName+' content goes here!!</br>ID='+pId+'</p>');
        }
    else {
        //load Person Details
        //eventually replace this with dynamic content from php file
        $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">'+pName+' content goes here!!</br>ID='+pId+'</p>');
        }
    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
    $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

    $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent center").hide();
        $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
        // activate the previous tab
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
        $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#c"+count).remove();
        return false;
    });
}
});
```

Note that essentially, I've just changed the `$("#tabcontent p")` part to `$("#tabcontent center")`. If this is not your intended html output, you might have to take a look at your html again.

Comment: I've made the change as you suggested to my online example and it does hide the initial content when I created a new tab, however a second and third tab's content is just appended to the bottom of the previous content.  And if you try clicking each tab the the content does not hide or reappear.  I don't need the center tags, they are just there to center the links for testing and will go away.

Comment: @GSMACK, I've edited my answer. Check the edit history. Also, I noticed that there is no function that binds clicks to tabs to display it's content. Try opening all tabs and clicking on other tabs, without closing them. The content does not change.

Comment: The addtab function includes a #close+count bind when the tab is created to handle the clicking of each tab.  In my online example at [tabs.html](http://coltsdigital.me/armoredkill/tabs.html), I have removed the center tags and changed everything back to "#tabcontent p".hide.  I've also changed the .php file to only return 1 table to limit the space.  You'll notice if you add all the tabs then click them separately, Tab 1,2,3 all replace each other's content on click of the tab.  It's just the first intital tab that doesn't hide.

Comment: Also, I have created [tabs2.html](http://coltsdigital.me/armoredkill/tabs2.html) and replaced the .get of the php file to just show text and everything works perfect.  It appears the css and tables loading from the php file is wrecking the code.  If you view the source of [test7.php](http://coltsdigital.me/armoredkill/test7.php) you'll find no markup errors, no element name conflicts, and just standard css & table.